# Configuration system failed to initialize with <system.serviceModel>

Tags: wcf, app-config

I'm trying to make a client that places messages into a queue on a server via WCF. Using a combination of various websites, forum posts etc I've written code that draws upon the App.config below.

When I do the simple operation of retrieving the CryptoCoordinatorQueueName, I get an exception. If I comment out the system.serviceModel and bindings sections, the exception goes away and the string is correctly returned. The exception is "Configuration system failed to initialize", and digging down I see the inner exception "Unrecognized element" and a line number corresponding to the  tag. System.ServiceModel is referenced by the project, but it looks like this isn't enough to make the configuration system accept the element. Can anyone see how to fix this? I'm using dotnet 4 and VS2010.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <configuration>

      <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" 
                      type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
          <section name="CryptoCoordinatorServiceTest.Properties.Settings" 
                   type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
      </configSections>

      <appSettings>
        <add key="CryptoCoordinatorQueueName" value=".\private$\CryptoCoordinatorQueue" />
      </appSettings>

      <system.serviceModel>
          <services>
              <service behaviorConfiguration="MetadataBehavior" name="CryptoCoordinatorService.CryptoCoordinatorQueue">
                  <endpoint
                    address="net.msmq://localhost/private/CryptoCoordinatorQueue"
                    binding="netMsmqBinding"
                    contract="CryptoCoordinatorService.ICryptoCoordinatorControlQueue"
                    bindingConfiguration="CryptoCoordinatorNetMsmqBinding"/>
                  <endpoint
                    address="mex"
                    binding="mexHttpBinding"
                    contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
                  <host>
                      <baseAddresses>
                          <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/CryptoCoordinatorQueue/"/>
               
                    </baseAddresses>
           
                  </host>
                </service>
     
          </services>
      </system.serviceModel>

      <bindings>
          <netMsmqBinding>
              <binding name="CryptoCoordinatorNetMsmqBinding" deadLetterQueue="Custom">
                  <security mode="None"/>
                </binding>
     
          </netMsmqBinding>

      </bindings>



    </configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah. I tried looking at the app.config file with a hex editor and found some whitespace contained 0xA0 characters as well as the expected 0x20. Somewhere in copying and pasting fragments between webpages, OneNote and Visual Studio, something has gone weirdly wrong.

Pasting the file into an online cleaner (in this case http://www.ubertoolz.com/demo/CleanUp.php) and pasting it back resolved the problem. Pasting it into Notepad didn't remove the garbage. The formatting's screwed since it's also stripped the tab characters, but that's a minor irritation.

Answer (score 0):

Move your bindings element so that it's a child of system.serviceModel:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        ...
    </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think that's an error I've not hit yet; I've made the change but I still get the same "Unrecognised element" exception thrown at the first system.serviceModel tag.